# Index on foreign keys

Tags: t-sql, foreign-keys, indexing

I'm just trying to best understand index.

On pg 106 of 70-461 - Querying Microsoft Sql Server 2012,
it says when a primary or unique constraint SQL Sever will automatically create a unique index.

But no index are created for foreign keys.

Therefore to make joins more efficient is it best to just create a non_clustered index on the foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what part is the question.

An index is used to enforce a unique constraint.

A FK by nature does not require an index.
But if the FK has an index the query optimizer will often use it in the join.

In this query docMVEnum1.valueID is a FK with an index.
The query optimizer used that index.
Even with the index it was still the most expensive part of the query.

```
select  docMVEnum1.sID, docEnum1.value
  from  docMVEnum1  
  join  docEnum1 
    on  docEnum1.valueID = docMVEnum1.valueID
```

Also by nature a FK is often used in a where clause.

Indexes are not free.
They improve select but slow down insert and update.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to create a `index` for the `foreign keys`, it will not promise that it will make joins more efficient.

The indexes for unique and PK are created to improve the INSERT and UPDATE performance.

While you are querying with `JOIN` it will use **zero or one index** to seek / scan the table.
Lets say that you have couple of tables like

```
MyTable
(
  ID int (PK),
  Description varchar(max),
  ColumnFK int (FK to LookupTable) 
)
Table LookupTable 
(
   ID int (PK), 
   Description varchar(max)
)

SELECT MyTable.ID, MyTable.Description, MyTable.ColumnFK, LookupTable.Description
FROM MyTable 
INNER JOIN LookupTable 
   on LookupTable.ID = MyTable.ColumnFK,
WHERE ID between 5 and 10000
```

most probably is that the profiler will use `index scan` to find all the relevant `ID`s in `MyTable` so it will pick from `Mytable` columns `ColumnFK1` and `Description`.

if you were thinking of adding the FK to the `unique` or `pk` just evaluate what happens if you are going to have many FK in the same table?

Note that intentionally I added to the predicate `MyTable.Description` and made it varchar(max) to show that you will reach the data for such a query.